# java code not exporting buffered image when no errors are present

Tags: java, bufferedimage, imageicon, drawimage

My Java code below places a image on a label.The button when triggered should export the image. There are no runtime error but nothing is being exported. I assume the issue is during the conversion from image icon to buffered image which occurs  in  b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {. I am not seeing anything exported at all not even a blank image.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ren {
    Frame f;
    JLabel b2 = new JLabel("");

    ren() throws IOException {
        f = new JFrame();
        b2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/johnzalubski/Desktop/dropIn/Complete-Audi-Buying-Guide-gear-patrol-lead-full.jpg"));

        JButton b3 = new JButton("Exported");

        File file = new File("aa.png");

        f.add(b2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(b3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        f.setSize(400, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);

        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Icon ico = b2.getIcon();
                // Create a buffered image
                BufferedImage bimg = new BufferedImage(ico.getIconWidth(), ico.getIconHeight(),
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                // Create the graphics context
                Graphics g = bimg.createGraphics();
                // Now paint the icon
                ico.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
                g.dispose();

                BufferedImage scaledButtonImage =
                        new BufferedImage(400, 1000, bimg.getType());
                Graphics g1 = scaledButtonImage.createGraphics();
                g1.drawImage(scaledButtonImage, 0, 0, 400, 1000, null);
                //                  
                g1.dispose();

                b2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bimg));

                try {
                    ImageIO.write(bimg, "png", file);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ren();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it's running and exporting. May be the issue in the permission. Have you try to put path new File("./aa.png") or may be full path? Also I added final in file, final File file = new File...

Comment: Did you add a image from your own computer.

Comment: I build and run from eclipse when I built it from the terminal it work. Why does eclipse not export the image? If you know thanks.

Comment: --------------- yes

Comment: I've tried from eclipse and it is also running well. I think the issue is about permission in your os

Comment: ok I will look into but If I just build it from terminal javac it works.

Comment: try to create a simple file from eclipse and see if it works